# How do we set refresh rate of Google Docs published document?

Tags: google-drive, google, scheduling

When I publish a Google Docs text file onto the web, it is set to update automatically every five minutes. I would like it to refresh itself more frequently.

I was wondering is there anyway to set it to refresh at a shorter interval, like three minutes (or every minute if possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the refresh rate to a custom time interval does not seem to be supported at this time.

You could check the [Google Docs Product Ideas](https://www.google.com/moderator/#15/e=87e7f&t=87e7f.40) to see if anyone has suggested this feature. If no one has suggested it, you should just submit it as an feature idea.

Comment: crap they are no longer accepting new ideas

Comment: @Pacerier Really? That sucks...